# SQL function appears to be stuck in loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, while-loop

I am currently working on a function that should be returning 3 business days prior to the date sent as an argument to the function.

I am somewhat new to functions in SQL and I believe my logic is sound but I am stuck.

I have 2 tables I made. One contains all the weekend dates and one contains all the holiday dates. The function is meant to take in a single date and then using 2 while loops calculate 3 business days prior to the date submitted and then return that new date into my select statement.

Here is the function in quesion:

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[lessThreeBD](@WORKING_DT DATE)  
RETURNS DATE   
AS  
BEGIN
DECLARE @ThreeBD DATE
DECLARE @COUNTER INT
SET @COUNTER = 0

WHILE @COUNTER < 4
SET @ThreeBD = @WORKING_DT
BEGIN
    WHILE CASE WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 HOL.DATE from DATABASE.dbo.Holidays HOL where HOL.DATE = CAST(@WORKING_DT AS DATE)) IS NULL THEN 'NOT HOLIDAY' ELSE 'HOLIDAY' END = 'HOLIDAY'
    OR CASE WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 WKND.DATE from DATABASE.dbo.Weekends WKND where WKND.DATE = CAST(@WORKING_DT AS DATE)) IS NULL THEN 'WEEKDAY' ELSE 'WEEKEND' END = 'WEEKEND'
    BEGIN
        SET @WORKING_DT = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @WORKING_DT)
    END
    SET @WORKING_DT = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @WORKING_DT)
    SET @COUNTER  = @COUNTER + 1
SET @ThreeBD = @WORKING_DT
END
RETURN @ThreeBD
END
```

However when I test this with a single date it appears to be locked up:

Test line:

```
SELECT DATABASE.dbo.lessThreeBD('2020-05-24') AS TESTING
```

This line should return the 20th.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Keep in mind that both the holiday and weekend tables work perfectly fine. I have already tested the case statements and I get the expected results with each case statement.

Comment: Can you share with us the results of: ***SELECT TOP 1 HOL.DATE from DATABASE.dbo.Holidays HOL where HOL.DATE = CAST(@WORKING_DT AS DATE))*** and of: ***SELECT TOP 1 WKND.DATE from DATABASE.dbo.Weekends WKND where WKND.DATE = CAST(@WORKING_DT AS DATE))***

Comment: @VBoka I was originally assuming no results is = NULL but after testing again using SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(WKND.DATE, 'BaseType') I realized nothing comes back if no results. So it appears I need to define if no results. Probable use a cont instead and then if count is not zero then condition is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
WHILE @COUNTER < 4
SET @ThreeBD = @WORKING_DT
```

is equivilent to

```
WHILE @COUNTER < 4
BEGIN
  SET @ThreeBD = @WORKING_DT
END
```

which is an infinite loop.

Always use BEGIN / END with control flow statements in TSQL.

```
WHILE @COUNTER < 4
BEGIN
  SET @ThreeBD = @WORKING_DT
  BEGIN
. . .
```

Except, perhaps, for common idioms like

```
if @@trancount > 0 rollback;
```

Comment: So I have to write in another BEGIN/END for the first set?

Comment: I think you can just delete the `SET @ThreeBD = @WORKING_DT` between `WHILE @COUNTER < 4` and `BEGIN`.  it doesn't appear to have any effect.

Comment: I did do that but still stuck

Comment: I managed to fix it. For some reason the select statement itself was not returning the value as NULL but after adding `SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(WKND.DATE, 'BaseType')` I was getting the correct null type returned. Well kinda fixed it. I am getting dates now but they are much further down than 3 business days. Almost 2 10 days but that is probably something I can fix in the logic. At least now I am getting nulls returned properly.

Comment: Got it working perfectly now. Ended up having to say IS NOT NULL in stead of IS NULL. The loop is working fine it was my null values that failed.

Comment: Actually it was a combination of a few things. Your mention of the loop due to set being outside of the begin and the null issue. So thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is here:

`WHILE @COUNTER < 4
SET @ThreeBD = @WORKING_DT
BEGIN`

this SET command is being executed in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the null issue and the issue with SET not being inside of BEGIN I had to make a couple more changes to make this work accuratly.

The final function is as follows for anyone who would like it for their own use:

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[lessThreeBD](@WORKING_DT DATE)  
RETURNS DATE   
AS  
BEGIN
    DECLARE @COUNTER INT
    SET @COUNTER = 0

    WHILE @COUNTER < 3
    BEGIN
        SET @WORKING_DT = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @WORKING_DT)
        SET @COUNTER  = @COUNTER + 1
        WHILE (SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY((SELECT TOP 1 HOL.DATE as CT from crmCAST.dbo.Holidays HOL where HOL.DATE = CAST(@WORKING_DT AS DATE)), 'BaseType')) IS NOT NULL
        OR (((DATEPART(DW, @WORKING_DT) - 1 ) + @@DATEFIRST ) % 7) IN (0,6)
        BEGIN
            SET @WORKING_DT = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @WORKING_DT)
        END
    END
RETURN @WORKING_DT
END
```

I was able to remove my weekend table with the use of `(((DATEPART(DW, @WORKING_DT) - 1 ) + @@DATEFIRST ) % 7) IN (0,6)` that will tell me if the date is a weekend so the only thing you will need is a table that has a list of holidays your business observes so you can have an accurate 3 business day return.